# In combat situations would one eidolon with 8 feats be more useful compared to 8 eidolons with one feat each?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, eidolon

As related to a previous question I asked I am planning to play as a Broodmaster.  I will need to distribute feats between my Eidolons, but I can't decide whether it would be more effective to give all feats to one Eidolon or if it would be wiser to divide the feats between Eidolons.

#### In terms of combat effectiveness, is it better to spread out the feats between my Eidolons, or concentrate the feats in one Eidolon?

Comment: I'm not sure the title is doing justice to your question. So far as I can tell, the broodmaster only gets 2 eidolons. (It would also be awesome if you linked to stuff—rather than using just names—so folks don't have to hunt that stuff down themselves… especially if you're going to refer to your own other questions!)

Comment: Will you please link to the previous question?  Also, please review the edit to make sure it retains your original intent. If not, please edit again.

Comment: @HeyICanChan It might be worth VtC for "unclear" given the points you raised.  I tried to edit in what I think the core question is (and as  you noted, the title does not do it justice)  but when I look at Bainos' answer it occurs to me that the question needs some more work.

Comment: @Maiko Could you clarify your Broodmaster build, and how you're getting 8 eidolons?

Comment: Most likely through the Larger Brood feature "At 13th level, if the broodmaster has purchased the large evolution for his brood, he can spend an additional 6 evolution points from the evolution pool for the huge evolution [...]. This allows him to call [...] eight Small eidolons"

Comment: @SimpleLime There you go! As the current broodmaster expert, how about editing the question to make it clear that's its purpose?

Answer (score 1):

It will mostly depend on what feats you are planning to give them.

For example, you can increase the damage per round by giving both of your eidolons Power Attack and Improved Natural Attack, but you would give up on feat-intensive builds such as Cleave and Vital Strike.

It's difficult to give you a more precise answer without an actual build to look at.